# get only property name and value from getGetFeatureInfoUrl WMS layer ol5

Tags: openlayers

Stuck in a problem to get only property name and value of WMS layer.
here is my code

```
var point_wms = new ol.layer.Image({
  title: 'Gound Control Point',

    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({

        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',

        params: {
            'LAYERS': 'export:Ground_Control_Point',

            'VERSION': '1.1.1',
            'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                'tiled': true, 
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
        }
    }),
     visible: true,
    opacity: 1
});

map.on('singleclick', getFeatureInformation);

function getFeatureInformation(evt){
        var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
        var lonLat = ol.proj.transform(coordinate,'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326');
        var viewResolution = (map.getView().getResolution());

        if(point_wms.getVisible()){
            var url = point_wms.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
              evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
              {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
            console.log("url = "+url);
                if (url) {
                  content.innerHTML ='<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
                }

                 overlay.setPosition(coordinate);

            }
}
```

it shows result like

[image]

but i want to get property name and value so that i can show this result using my html code in desired format like vertical table. how to achieve this?

i edited the question here is my code

```
 if(point_wms.getVisible()){
            var url = point_wms.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
              evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
              {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'});
                /*console.log("url = "+url);
                if (url) {
                  content.innerHTML ='<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
                }*/
            if (url) {
                var parser = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
                console.log(parser)
                $.ajax({
                      url: url,
                      dataType: 'jsonp',
                      jsonpCallback: 'parseResponse'
                    }).then(function(response) {
                      var result = parser.readFeatures(response);
                       console.log("result.length = "+result.length);
                      if (result.length) {

                        var iso3 = [];
                        for (var i = 0, ii = result.length; i < ii; ++i) {
                          iso3.push(result[i].get('Point_Id'));
                        } 
                         content.innerHTML = iso3.join(',');
                         overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
                      }
                    });
              }


            }
```

still not getting value of point_id.

it is showing error like this

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at m (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
    at text script (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Ut (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException code="ForbiddenFormat">
      Getting feature info using application/json is not allowed
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Comment: I can't work out if your problem is that the GetFeatureInfo response doesn't contain the information you want, or it contains the information together with other feature information.  Can you edit the question to add that information.

Comment: Set `INFO_FORMAT` parameter of `GetFeatureInfo` request to `application/json` and then you can use returned JSON data.

Comment: edited the question please go through it. after adding application/json still not getting value.

Comment: oh thanks finally solved my problem by adding application/json format to Allowed MIME types for a GetFeatureInfo request in geoserver.

Comment: please add that as an answer (and accept it later) for the benefit of future users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by adding application/json format to Allowed MIME types for a GetFeatureInfo request in geoserver.

[image]

go to WMS and just add  application/json format to Allowed MIME types for a GetFeatureInfo request in geoserver

[image]